# ASP.NET MVC site and cookies with same name but different domains

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, cookies, cross-domain

I have this issue where a cookie never gets set because I believe it's using the wrong one.  This is happening on `play.exposureevents.store`.  I have no idea how, but a `exposureevents.com` cookies is available on this domain somehow.  I believe when trying to authenticate it is using the .exposureevents.com cookie and never setting the correct cookie.  Is there a way in ASP.NET to either remove the wrong cookie, or set the correct one?

**Create Cookie On Login**

```
public SiteMemberModel CreateAuthenticationCookie(string username, Guid userId, string roles)
{
    var member = GetMemberProfile(userId, username);

    var ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
        2,
        username,
        DateTime.Now,
        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(FormsAuthentication.Timeout.TotalMinutes),
        false,
        JsonConvert.SerializeObject(member, Formatting.None),
        FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath);

    var cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName, FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket))
    {
        Secure = true,
        Path = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookiePath,
        SameSite = SameSiteMode.None
    };

    if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.IsLocal)
    {
        cookie.Domain = Helper.GetDomain();
    }

    if (ticket.IsPersistent)
        cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

    return member;
}
```

**Web.config**

```
<httpCookies requireSSL="true" sameSite="None" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="/login" path="/" cookieSameSite="None" requireSSL="true" protection="All" timeout="2880" slidingExpiration="true" name="_EXPOSURE_" />
</authentication>
```

[image]

Comment: See a detailed breakdown of how web cookies work here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18492576/share-cookies-between-subdomain-and-domain

Comment: I might not understand exact problem but it seems you are setting shared cookie across sub domains by setting cookie.Domain = Helper.GetDomain(); so it's expected that _EXPOSURE_ must exists in all subdomains.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since .NET 4.8 doesn't give you a way to update a cookie via a domain name with same cookie name back to the response, we went with a different cookie name for the actual other domains.  This seems to be working great and had no issues changing it in the Web.config since it had it's own.

Answer (score 0):

**YOUR DEPLOYMENT?**

Your question could be improved if you explained your hosting domain names, any infrastructure such as reverse proxies. The authentication cookie is the important one and by default is named `.ASPXAUTH`, yet is not shown in your screenshot. My answer describes some common causes of HTTP cookies not sticking.

**BROWSER COOKIES**

Any backend component that sets cookies typically has an external URL and an internal URL. Examples here for a Kubernetes setup:

```
External URL: https:///www.example.com
Internal URL: http://applicationhost-svc.applications.svc:3000
```

The cookie that counts is the one that corresponds to the browser in the URL address bar, which is the external URL. That is what the user agent will look for when it receives and sends cookies.

**BACKEND COMPONENT BEHAVIOR**

The following backend components set cookies and use both internal and external URLs:

- Website
- Utility API
- Authorization server
- Identity provider

Such components may need to be configured with settings like `COOKIE_DOMAIN` and `EXTERNAL_BASE_URL`. Personally I always prefer to be explicit about these so that I know my code is doing the right thing.

If no cookie domain is set, then that will also work and user agents will interpret that as an exact match on the external host name. Though some technology stacks may incorrectly set a cookie domain to the internal host name.

**THIRD PARTY COOKIES**

The [RFC6265bis specification](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-13) was published a few years ago and introduced a `SameSite` concept, whose goal is to protect user privacy. This was subsequently implemented by all main browsers.

If you ever set a cookie for a domain whose [SameSite calculation](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-ietf-httpbis-rfc6265bis-13#section-5.2) does not match that of the URL in the browser address bar, the cookie will be classified as third party and dropped aggressively by user agents. Perhaps this explains your issue?

Another possible cause for cookies not sticking can be the use of invalid top level domains. A while back I had an issue where cookies with a suffix of `.local` were rejected by the Safari browser.

As a side note, the above spec also introduced stronger cookies with best protection against cross site request forgery. This is `SameSite=strict` and should be used by normal web applications. The `SameSite=none` setting is typically only used by authorization servers and identity providers, to manage externalized logins.